# run js function in python which calls another js function

Tags: javascript, python

I know I can call JavaScript function in python with `js2py` like below :

```
import execjs
import  js2py
un ='''
function sample(x)
{
    return x
}
'''
print(js2py.eval_js(un)("Hi"))
```

but my function in JavaScript calls another function, how can handle it in Python?

```
import execjs
import  js2py



un ='''
function sample(x)
{
    return func2(x)
}
'''
print(js2py.eval_js(un)("Hi"))
```

thre maybe more than 2 Functions

Comment: @Arman  tnx for edit

Answer (score 0):

One can define multiple functions in the string. Note that js2py **runs the last function first**.

```
import  js2py
un ='''
function func2(q) {
    return q + " World";
}
function sample(x) {
    return func2(x) + "!";
}
'''
print(js2py.eval_js(un)("Hello"))
```

This prints the always heartwarming `Hello World!`